# Convert CHAR to Date?

Tags: sql, teradata

Having a hard time using a column as Date. Its currently in MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM format and I am struggling to convert/cast into date format. Here is the format below.

11/04/2021 12:00

I am able to convert the varchar into char but am not able to use as a date. Any suggestion would be great.

Comment: Use `to_date('11/04/2021 12:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out if this helps

```
select convert(char(10), getdate(), 101)


+ ' ' + convert(char(5), getdate(), 108);
```

Thanks!

Comment: That helped!! as well as @stefanov.sm, needed a combination but thank you all for the help